# PouchDB error 'web_sql_went_bad' reason 'database has been closed'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB this error coming in console of browser.

- Using PouchDB in Ionic2 with Angular2
- This error come sometimes in console - when ionic serve is done.